# java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider from ProcessRecord

Tags: android, installation

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider
>   android.support.v4.content.FileProvider from ProcessRecord

```
<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="cn.cloudworkshop.miaoding.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            tools:replace="android:authorities">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"
                tools:replace="android:resource"/>
        </provider>
```

**java code:**

```
 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE)) {
            Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            Uri contentUri;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                install.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "cn.cloudworkshop.miaoding.fileprovider", file);
            } else {
                contentUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

            }
            install.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            install.setDataAndType(contentUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            context.startActivity(install);
        }
    }
```

> install.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

This code leads to this question,but I delete this code,this app will crash after installed.

Comment: Did you set file provider path in xml ?

Comment: <paths>
    <root-path name="root" path="" />
    <external-path name="external" path="" />
</paths>

Comment: is this path empty ? also could you post stack trace of crash ?

Comment: no,ti's OK, if I delete "install.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)",it can be installed

Comment: @DevKRos   after installation is complete,the page of installation result doesn't appear

Comment: Did you fill  in the "root" path="" /> <external-path name="external" path="" /> </paths> part or its blank ? secondly .Did you obtain runtime permission for writing on external storage ?

Answer (score 5):

Baby~  you cant try this way:

```
installIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
```

I guess need put together , permission allow activity_new_task!

Comment: Yeah, this works, But anyone please explain what's the difference between the way he set the flag?